# Collision detection affects entity's neighbor

Tags: c#, xna, detection

While working on a collision detection in my training Space Invaders variation I came to the problem that every time an alien gets hit by a rocket, its (right) neighbor's position is being changed.

```
for (int i=0; i < alienEntity.Count; i++) // Move aliens
{
    alienEntity[i].position = new Vector2((int)(alienEntity[i].position.X + alienMovingDirection * alienMovingSpeed), alienEntity[i].position.Y);
    Rectangle alienRect = new Rectangle((int)(alienEntity[i].position.X), (int)(alienEntity[i].position.Y), alienTexture.Width, alienTexture.Height);
    for (int j = 0; j < rocketEntity.Count; j++)
    {
        if (alienRect.Intersects(rocketRect[j]))
        {
            rocketEntity.RemoveAt(j);
            rocketRect.RemoveAt(j);
            alienEntity.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The x-position of the right-hand neighbor of the deleted alien gets affected by either adding 1 or subtracting 1. The screenshot shows the the horizontal gaps between the aliens, which should make the affected neighbors visible.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I suspect the position of your invader ships depends on their position in the list.

Comment: Somehow it does, I set all the positions in the Initialize method. But their position is only changed by this part of code, where they also are removed after they collide with rockets. So after initializing the alien's position doesn't depend on their index.

Comment: You can probably find out what's going on by watching what code changes the aliens' positions. Try making the position field a property and set a debug stop point at the `set` accessor to see which code calls it via the call stack panel.

Comment: I fixed the problem in another way. I created a seperate loop for the collision detection instead of having one loop both for moving and collision. This way it works now.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer to your question, that way it will help others with similar problem.